# Ebean doesn't update my postgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, playframework, ebean, play-authenticate

I downloaded play-authenticate with its "play-authenticate-usage" example and changed from the h2 database implementation to the postgreSQL database.

When I pick a specific User out of the table called "users", I can edit the values but after executing the method:

```
EbeanServer server = Ebean.getDefaultServer();
server.update(editedUser);
```

the changed values are not written into the postgreSQL database.
I can Insert new Users and I can delete them, just updating doesn't work with the Ebean ORM.

(With the h2 database everything worked well, but I have to integrate the postgreSQL database.)